# Convolution of $f(x)={1 \over 2} \chi_{[-1,1]}*\chi_{[-5,5]}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution

Convolution of $f(x)={1 \over 2} \chi_{[-1,1]}*\chi_{[-5,5]}$. This is my first exercise, it's basically an interpolation between the two functions. So here my results:

Calling $u={1 \over 2} \chi_{[-1,1]}$ and $v=\chi_{[-5,5]}$ I can calculate the different values:

$u*v(0)={ 3 \over 2}$

$u*v({1 \over 2})={ 3 \over 2}$

$u*v(-{1 \over 2})={ 3 \over 2}$

So for the borders, we have:

- $0$ for $x<-5,x>5$
- $1$ for $x \geq -5,x \leq -{ 3\over 4}$
- $-x+{ 3 \over 4}$ for $-{ 3\over 4} \leq x \leq -{ 1 \over 4}$
- ${ 3 \over 2}$ for $-{ 1 \over 4} \leq x \leq { 1 \over 4}$
- $x-{ 3 \over 4}$ for ${ 1 \over 4} \leq x \leq { 3 \over 4}$
- $1$ for $x \geq { 3 \over 4},x\leq5$

I hope it's right (I can't draw the graphic here); if there is some error or not rigorous passage, please let me know I want to be capable to solve this at the best of possibilities

Comment: So, you want to find out what the convolution of these two functions is? What is meant by "$0$ for $x<5$,$x>5$"?

Comment: I took the two functions, and evaluated the borders; I miss something?

Comment: Yes. Read what I wrote (and what you wrote). Carefully!

Comment: Ok, that was an error! Edited! Thanks! Anyway, is the solution ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X_{[-5,5]}(y)X_{[-1,1]}(x-y)dy$

$$X_{[-1,1]}(x-y)=1 \Longleftrightarrow -1 \leq x-y \leq 1 $$$$\Longleftrightarrow x-1\leq y \leq x+1 \Longleftrightarrow y \in[x-1,x+1]\Longleftrightarrow X_{[x-1,x+1]}(y)=1$$

Thus $X_{[-1,1]}(x-y)=X_{[x-1,x+1]}(y)$

Also $G(y)=X_{[-5,5]}(y)X_{[x-1,x+1]}(y)=X_{[-5,5] \cap [x-1,x+1]}(y)$

$1.$ If $|x| \leq 4$ then $[x-1,x+1] \cap [-5,5]=[x-1,x+1]$ thus $G(y)=X_{[x-1,x+1]}(y) \Longrightarrow f(x)=1$

$2.$ If $x-1>5$ the the intervals are disjoint so the integral is zero,so $f(x)=0$

$3.$ If $x+1<-5$ again as in $2$ we have $f(x)=0$

$4.$ If $x=-6,6$ the intersection of the intervals is a singleton set so $f(x)=0$

$5.$ If $-6<x<-4$ then $x+1<-3$ and $x-1<-5$ and $-5<x+1<-3 $ and the intersection of the intervals is $[-5,x+1]$ thus  $f(x)=\int_{-5}^{x+1}dy=\frac{x+6}{2}$

$6.$ If $4<x<6$ then $x+1>5$ and $3<x-1<5$  then  the intersection is the interval $[x-1,5]$ thus $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^{5}dy=\frac{6-x}{2}$

Comment: This method is general for all convolutions right?

Comment: This method is in general for convolutions of indicator functions of elementary sets, of balls,cubes in $\Bbb{R}^d$ and intervals on the line. ...but in general there is no general method..the outcome depends on the functions you convolve

Comment: I think that's enough for my current exam... thank you for your lesson

Comment: You are welcome.!

Comment: Question, why in the 1st point there is no trace of the first characteristic function?

Comment: @Alessar on $1.$ if $|x| \leq 4 $ then $[x-1,x+1] \cap [-5,5]=[x-1,x+1]$...edited my answer to be more clear

Comment: Note that  $X_A(y)X_B(y)=X_{A \cap B}(y)$

Comment: It s too late to ask some details about point 5 and 6 of your great answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Alessar ask me

Comment: I have some trouble to identify the intersection of those intervals; I know seems naive, but I can't really be sure on how it's done

Comment: @Alessar in 5,6 just follow the inequalities to see the intersection of $[-5,5] \cap [x-1,x+1]$..you can draw the numbers to a line and see why the intersection this..it is not difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Is known that

> $$\mathcal L(h(x-b)) = \dfrac1s e^{-bs},$$
> $$\mathcal L((x-b)h(x-b)) = \dfrac1{s^2} e^{-bs},$$
> $$\mathcal L(u(x)*v(x)) = \mathcal L(u(x)) \mathcal L(v(x)),$$
>
> where $\mathcal L(f(x))$ is Laplace transform,
> $$h(t)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0,\quad\text{if}\quad t\in(-\infty,0]\\
> 1,\quad\text{otherwize}
> \end{cases}$$
> is the Heaviside function.

So
$$u(x)=\dfrac12(h(x-1)-h(x+1)),\quad v(x)=h(x-5)-h(x+5),$$
$$\mathcal L(u(x)*v(x)) = \dfrac1{2s^2}(e^{-5s}-e^{5s})(e^{-s}-e^s)
 = \dfrac1{2s^2}(e^{-6s}-e^{-4s}-e^{4s}+e^{6s}),$$
$$u(x)*v(x) = \dfrac12\left((t+6)h(t+6)- (t+4)h(t+4)- (t-4)h(t-4)+ (t-6)h(t-6)\right),$$
$$u(x)*v(x)=\begin{cases}
0,\quad\text{if}\quad x \in(-\infty, -6]\\
\dfrac t2+3,\quad\text{if}\quad x \in(-6, -4]\\
1,\quad\text{if}\quad x \in(-4, 4]\\
3- \dfrac t2,\quad\text{if}\quad x \in(4, 6]\\
0,\quad\text{if}\quad x \in(6,\infty).
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is really interesting! I didn't knew the Laplace transform

Comment: @Alessar You are welcome! Also, Laplace transform is very poverful instrument for the linear ODE systems etc.